# How can I pass arguments like these for example: runType=EOD threadCnt=10 cleanLogs=true in my commandline java program?

Tags: java, spring

What is the best way to pass these arguments to a java commandline program. Currently, I have order dependent args that the user must remember. My program is called as below:

`CommandLineRunner EOD 10 true`

I want the user to be able to do this:

`CommandLineRunner runType=EOD threadCnt=10 cleanLogs=true`

Or change order of arguments.

`CommandLineRunner threadCnt=10 runType=EOD cleanLogs=true`

I would prefer not to use an external library for this but if there is a good one in java, please provide an example of how to use it to build my example. The `=` signs must be there since I need to make this program follow a standard for other python/ruby based cli applications we have in our organization.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the parameters in the command line just after the main class:

```
java CommandLineRunner "runType=EOD" "threadCnt=10" "cleanLogs=true"
```

Then in the program:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        //Collect the input parameters...
        HashMap<String, String> argsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(args[i], "=");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String key = st.nextToken();
                //Handle the case you don't define a key/value with '='
                try{
                    String val = st.nextToken();
                    argsMap.put(key, val);
                }catch(NoSuchElementException e){
                    argsMap.put(key, "");
                }
            } 
        }

        //Then use them when needed...
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : argsMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("arg: "+ key + "\tval:" + value);

            if(key.equals("runType")){
                //Add your business logic here
            }
            else if (key.equals("threadCnt")){
                //Add your business logic here
            }
            else if (key.equals("cleanLogs")){
                //Add your business logic here
            }else
                //Unknown argument
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid argument!");
        }
    }
}
```

So you will have your arguments in your map, despite of their input order.

#### Note

From `Java7` you can use the more elegant `switch` construct to handle `String` (thus your arguments) too:

```
    //Then use them when needed...
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : argsMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        System.out.println("arg: "+ key + "\tval:" + value);

        switch (key) {
            case "runType":
                //Add your business logic here
                break;
            case "threadCnt":
                //Add your business logic here
                break;
            case "cleanLogs":
                //Add your business logic here
                break;
            default:
                //Unknown argument
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid argument!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are the command line arguments with quotations? Is this how I actually have to pass in the args to the program? `java CommandLineRunner "threadCnt=10" `

Comment: If you are sure you don't expect **spaces** inside the value of your key/value pair you can avoid to use the quotations.

Comment: To recap, `"runType=EOD"` is equivalent to `runType=EOD`, but `"runType=EO D"` is not equivalent to `runType=EO D` (as, in the second case, `D` will be seen as another parameter and it's probably not what you want).

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as you don't use spaces in the values:

```
java CommandLineRunner threadCnt=10 runType=EOD cleanLogs=true
```

Then you'll have to parse each of the three arguments.